# Split column into multiple columns based on character count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have only one column in a table.  Each row contains the exact same amount of characters.  I need a way to be able to split this one column into multiple columns.  The table has over 1.1 million rows, so efficiency in code is pretty important.  All of the rows are set up with the same structure, meaning the first 5 characters are always dedicated for firstname, the next 6 are always for lastname for example.  I know how to take the left most characters using:

```
insert into table2
select left(column1,2), substring(column1, 3, len(column1) ) from table1
```

The problem with the above, is that 1) it creates a new table instead of modifying the existing.  And 2) Once I have the first set of characters split into a column I don't know how to grab the next set.

Below is an example of how I would like it to work:

Current

Column 1

- abcdefghijklmnop
- qrstuvwxyz123456

What I would like:

Column 1 ----------- Column 2 --------- Column 3

- abcdefg--------------hij----------------klmnop
- qrstuvw--------------xyz----------------123456

picture below:

[image: Example]

I can usually fix this through how I important the data in SQL.  However the txt file that I use to import the data has no way to dilimate the columns correctly so it has to all be brought in as one column.

Comment: please post expected results,sample results as text

Comment: I am having trouble trying to figure out how to do a line break to make the columns match up?  Is there a charter symbol to symbolize it?

Comment: This is a good online tool for user for making tables: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

Comment: @HasibIbradzic, your question is not clear. first what do you mean of "multiple columns" , do you mean 2 columns? per your insert query, you already knew the answer. It is not clear what you are looking for. In your second problem, you said "the next set" what do you mean of next set, based on your insert query, you only have 2 columns, what is the rest?

Comment: If the file you are importing is fixed width why not specify it as fixed width when you import it? Then you don't have to wrestle it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the exact scenario that you have mentioned here.

```
DROP TABLE dbo.table1
DROP TABLE dbo.table2

CREATE TABLE dbo.table1
 (column1 VARCHAR(100))

CREATE TABLE dbo.table2
 (column1 VARCHAR(100),
  column2 VARCHAR(100),
  column3 VARCHAR(100)
 )

INSERT INTO dbo.table1
VALUES ('abcdefghijklmnop'),('qrstuvwxyz123456')

INSERT INTO dbo.table2
SELECT LEFT(column1,7) AS column1,SUBSTRING(column1,8,3) column2,RIGHT(column1,6) column3
FROM dbo.table1


SELECT *
FROM table1

SELECT *
FROM table2
```

Answer (score 0):

this should help

```
select 'dgfsrsdgsdghshdsdfhzhs' column1 into #table_name



ALTER TABLE #table_name
ADD firstname varchar(5) ,
    lastname varchar(6);


    update #table_name
    set firstname = SUBSTRING (column1,1,5),
     lastname = SUBSTRING (column1,6,6)


     select * from #table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the modification has to be done in the same table and SUBSTRING startposition and length are taken according the output that is being expected below code will do the needful 
    `UPDATE table1

     SET column1=SUBSTRING(c1,1,8),
     column2=SUBSTRING(c1,8,3),
     column3=SUBSTRING(c1,11,7)`